# How to develop Google maps in Windows Phone

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-phone-7

I am fresher for Windows Phone. I am working on windows phone 7.1. I worked on Bing maps control.

But I want to know is there any possibility to get the google maps api key for windows phone.

If there any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

This may help you,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153467/Google-Maps-for-Windows-Phone-7-using-Bing-Map-Con

Steps to create:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd3310/starting-with-google-map-in-windows-7-phone-application/

Comment: Accept this as solution if it helps

Comment: Great article, but they're tutorials for Bing Maps.

Comment: obviously not. both links are on using google maps on the windows phone